# Screen capture of web conference camera with Teams client SDK app

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I would like to add a function to Teams that captures the camera video of the Teams web conference and saves it as an image file.

Since I want to operate regardless of devices such as PCs, tablets, and smartphones, I need a capture function that works only with the Teams app without using other apps.

The camera image I want to capture is not on my side,
This is the image of the other party's camera in the web conference.

Is it possible to develop such a function with the Teams client SDK?
Or do I need another method?

I looked at the Microsoft Teams SDK reference, but as far as I could see, I couldn't find a method that would allow an app to access the web conference camera video.

Comment: Currently,You can access the following device capabilities on mobile or desktop through dedicated APIs available in Microsoft Teams JavaScript client library:
Media capabilities, such as Camera, Microphone, Gallery, QR or barcode scanner
Location.
Ref doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/device-capabilities-overview

Comment: We are checking with internal team if it is possible to Screen capture of web conference camera with Teams client SDK app or not.

Comment: Thank you. The information you provided is very helpful.
Please continue to check back.

Comment: Got the confirmation from engineering team,"If it is screen capture then that functionality is not supported as of now. As of now Teams JS SDK APIs only supporting capturing images either using camera or importing from phone's gallery and same goes for video."

Comment: Thank you very much. I think the design uses image capture using the camera.

Answer (score 0):

If it is screen capture then that functionality is not supported as of now. As of now Teams JS SDK APIs only supporting capturing images either using camera or importing from phone's gallery and same goes for video.